# MySQL net timeout not set

Tags: c#, mysql

I initialise the connection like this:

```
//open connection
conn = new MySqlConnection(DSN_INFO);
conn.Open();

//increase timeouts
using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999", conn))
{
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

then later use the connection to run an sql query

```
string sql = "select * from blah";
comm = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

However the later query always times out at 30 sec, so it looks like the net_read_timeout is being ignored. How do I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the timeout on the command. Like this:

```
comm.CommandTimeout=99999;
```